# How to set the same type for all arguments in this example?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Just for practice I'm trying to write a variadic template that inputs some values into vector. I wrote the following:

```
template <class T>
void add(vector<T> *v, T n){
    v->push_back(n);
}
template <class T, class... T2>
void add(vector<T> *v, T n, T2... rest){
    v->push_back(n);
    add(v, rest...);
}
```

To test these I use the following:

```
vector<int> vI;
add(&vI, 10, 30, 25);

for (int i = 0; i < vI.size(); i++)
    cout << vI[i] << endl;
```

Everything works as expected, but I'm wondering if the second template could be written in a way that it uses only one type (T or T2) since vector (push_back) expects the same type for all arguments? In fact, I would like to ensure T = T2 all the way.

Comment: Your recursive calls already ensure that, in a roundabout way.

Comment: I have an idea. Give me one moment

Comment: OK i remember what I was looking for. Have you thought of using initializer_list?

Comment: @Gasim No. I was just trying to eliminate T or T2 here. I know that there are probably more then one workaround for this but somehow it's illogical for me to must use T an T2 if they are both the same. I just wanted to know if it is possible to eliminate one of those here.

Comment: If you keep the vector variable outside the function, or if there is a function in C++ where you can extract the variable from a variadic one, you can achieve it using iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The funny thing is that your current code already ensures that calls like

```
add(&vI, 10, 10.f, 20);
```

doesn't compile. If an argument's type is different from the vector's value type, then eventually it will become the second argument in a call like

```
add(&vI, 10.f, 20);
```

and then template argument deduction will fail because it deduces conflicting types for `T`.

If you want to reduce the horrendous amount of error messages when the deduction failure happens deep in the recursion, SFINAE or `static_assert` can help. I personally prefer Columbo's trick:

```
template<bool...> class bool_pack;
template<bool...b>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, b...>, bool_pack<b..., true>>;

template <class T, class... T2>
void add(vector<T> *v, T n, T2... rest)
{
    static_assert(all_true<std::is_same<T, T2>{}...>{}, "T2 must be all Ts");
    v->push_back(n);
    add(v, rest...);
}
```

There is currently no way to avoid using both T and T2 (without modifying the call). The committee is considering potential improvements in this area, however, so something might make its way into the next standard.

Comment: Well, that was my question. If there is no way to avoid using both T and T2 in the declaration then there is nothing to be done but accept the current solution.

Comment: This is really clever! Couldn't you shorten it to just `std::is_same<std::tuple<T, T2...>, std::tuple<T2, T...>>`? Better still would be to have a more meaningful template name, say `typelist`, instead of using `std::tuple`.

Comment: @Pradhan You mean `<T2..., T>`? Sure, but I think having `is_same<T, T2>` in the condition is more self-documenting as to what's expected.

Comment: You would still have `is_same`. And assuming we have `template <typename ... T> typelist {}; ` defined, `static_assert(std::is_same<typelist<T, T2...>, typelist<T2..., T>>::value, "T2 must be all Ts");` looks clear. But of course, matter of taste. I am adding this trick to my arsenal. Thanks! :)

Comment: Scratch that. Yes, your form is indeed more self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a metafunction which ensures that all the types in the parameter pack `T2` are equal to `T`.

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct AllSame : public std::false_type{};

template <typename T>
struct AllSame<T> : public std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename U, typename ...Ts>
struct AllSame<T, U, Ts...> : public std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T,U>::value, AllSame<T, Ts...>, std::false_type>{};
```

Now use SFINAE on your return type:

```
template <class T, class... T2>
auto add(vector<T> *v, T n, T2... rest)
 -> std::enable_if_t<AllSame<T, T2...>::value>
{
    v->push_back(n);
    add(v, rest...);
}
```

Comment: `std::is_same<T,U>::value`.

Comment: Ok. But I was wondering if declaring both T and T2 could have been avoided. Instead just declaring T or T2, to be visible from the declaration itself that only one type is used in template function.