# Passing std::initializer_list as a non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include <deque>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

struct EnumItem
{
    inline operator int() const {
        return id;
    }

    std::string name;
    int id;
};

template <const std::initializer_list<EnumItem>& items>
class Enum
{
public:


private:
    static const std::deque<EnumItem> _items;
};

template <const std::initializer_list<EnumItem>& items>
const std::deque<EnumItem> Enum<items>::_items{ items };

int main() 
{
   Enum<{{"0", 0}}> test;
   return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile, throws numerous syntax errors about my `test` instantiation:

```
2>error C2059: syntax error : '{'    
2>error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'     
2>error C2143: syntax error : missing '>' before ';'     
2>error C2976: 'Enum' : too few template arguments     
2>: see declaration of 'Enum'       
2>error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)      
2>error C2059: syntax error : '>'
```

What am I doing wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot have a template argument of type `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: why not? Can't I have a template argument of any type at all?

Comment: Permitted types are mostly ints and pointers. (Full list [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).) You could use a parameter pack instead.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: the thought about parameter pack had crossed my mind, but I had hoped to avoid it because I don't quite understand the syntax and the usage nuances. It seems overcomplicated. I prefer to avoid writing the code I don't understand...

Comment: Furthermore, the order of the values in the initializer list does not match the order of the class members. But the main issue is, in fact, that template parameters must be ordinary values or types, and not class instances.

Comment: You use std::initializer_list with the intent to provide multiple template parameters. However, it is never more than a single template parameter. (Multiple elements in an  std::initializer_list is a runtime quality)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: fixed the order, no change. This is a  lvalue reference type, seems to be allowed for template parameter...

Comment: No, the template parameter is not an lvalue reference type. The template parameter is an ***instance*** of an lvalue reference type. Big difference.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: it appears that initalizing a container with template parameter pack is a whole new can of worms: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28866740/634821

Comment: @VioletGiraffe One rarely hears people calling C++ pretty. :)

Comment: @chris: "*C++17 lifts many restrictions on non-type template parameters.*" What proposal added this to C++?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I misremembered. I must have been thinking of [this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html), which does remove a bunch of restrictions on the *arguments*, but is unrelated to the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initializer_list` is not a type which can be used with non-type template parameters. In C++14, these are restricted to enums, integers, pointers of all kinds, lvalue references, and `nullptr_t`.