# Can we set default arguments for constructors? If yes, how?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

We need constructor overloading for running different instances of constructors based upon the number of formal arguments in the constructor. But I want to use one single version of constructor, and that should handle multiple cases of object call based on the number of actual arguments passed. For it, can we make constructors with default arguments in C++ ?

Comment: If you know the number of arguments at compile time then use a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) constructor. If all the arguments are of the same type, you may consider a vector of said arguments. I usually don't use default arguments just overloads (to avoid those with default arguments to be used in type deduction scenarios)

Comment: This is explained in any begginer level [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). See [Writing variadic template constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866559/writing-variadic-template-constructor)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can define default arguments

I will give an example

```cpp
class Test {
  public:
    Test(int x = 0, int y = 10) {
    
    }
};
```

Cheers, Daniel

Comment: I believe the asker is trying to do something more complicated.